# Unit test ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp

Всем привет! Когда из функции возвращаю:

1.BadRequest(obj) возвращается BadRequestResult, В postman правильный ответ и данные, юнит тест успешный.

2.Ok(obj) возвращается OkObjectResult. В postman правильный ответ и данные, юнит тест успешный.

3.Created("url",obj) возвращается CreatedResult. В postman правильный ответ и данные, юнит тест отрицательный по причине "System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

#### Почему я не могу вернуть данные через await или (Task).Result только в Created? как получить выходные данные?

использую NUnit 3, ASP.NET Core 2.2

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterModel formData)
    {
        if (formData == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Ok(new ResultDto
            {
                Errors = ModelState.GetErrors(), IsSuccess = false
            });
        }

        var userResult = await _repository.AddUserAsync(formData);


        if (userResult.IsSuccess)
        {
            return Created(Request.Path, userResult);
        }

        return Ok(userResult);
    }
```

[image: test]

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в строчке return Created(Request.Path, userResult);

недоглядел с Request.Path..